# How to turn jQuery/Javascript functions into methods

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, methods, object

Could anyone explain **how to** turn functions into methods and the variables into parameters of an object in jQuery/Javascript?

And even more interesting **Why** i should do that?

Comment: thy "why should I do that" can be translated to "why use OOP"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is (among others) the closure trick:

```
function obj(x, y) {
    var z = 0;

    return {
        foo: function() { z += x; return z; },
        bar: function() { z *= y; return z; }
    };
}

o = obj(2, 3);
o.foo();
```

This particular approach has the advantage that it hides internal state reasonably well. It is not easy (maybe impossible, but I'm not sure) to inadvertently tinker with z directly from outside the "object".

Answer (score 3):

in jQuery:

```
var MyClass = function( x, y ) {
  this.x = x;
  this.y = y;
};
$.extend(MyClass.prototype, {
  foo: function(z) { ... },
  bar: function() { ... }
});
```

than you could:

```
var myObject = new MyClass(1, 2);
```

or with [HJS plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/HJS):

```
var MyClass = $.Class.create({
  initialize: function(x, y) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
  }.
  foo: function(z) { ... },
  bar: function() { ... }
});
```